# Tool for generating a call flow graph [C C++ solaris linux]

Tags: c++, c, unix, call-graph, call-flow

I'm quite fond of [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/), but I'm working in Solaris on this project.  I do have a linux machine, and if nothing is in the same league as IDA then I'll convince management to purchase a license for it.

Barring that, I'm looking for alternative suggestions.  Some of the other features in IDA would be handy, but the main thing I need at the moment is a call flow graph generator **not** based on source code.  If it needs extra output from the build step, that's fine, but some of the libraries I need to look at I don't have source for.

So far, it looks like my best choices are Valgrind's [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html), [lida](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lida/), and [gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/).  Any further suggestions are welcome.

re: gprof, the GNU compiler set provided to us by Windriver is missing some libraries that would normally be supplied with a GNU compiler to provide (among other things) facilities for profiling.  It's a good solution to the more general problem, but for now I'm opting to try other solutions first.

*edit* Some of the Rational tools (Purify, Quantify, etc) might also work well for this.  I'm in the same boat as with IDA with that, but I figure someone googling might find the suggestion helpful.

*edit2* Valgrind hasn't been ported to solaris/sparc ;p

Comment: So, I guess doxygen with the graphviz plugin is out of the question?

Comment: Yes, OP mentioned that the generator should not be based on source code.

Comment: @Judge - I'm trying to generate a call-flow graph over some libraries I don't have source for.  I'm not familiar enough with doxygen/graphviz, but if they can work off a disassembly of the binary then I suppose that might work.

Comment: No, doxygen very much needs the source code, but it does make nice call graph diagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [ERESI Project](http://www.eresi-project.org/). It's a reverse engineering framework and it has a tool, called ELFsh, with capabilities of generating CFG from machine code. It doesn't have a stable/final yet, but it's worth a shot.

If you want to try it:

- download and install (apt-get on Ubuntu)
- run `elfsh32`. You'll enter a shell.
- load your binary: `load /bin/bash`
- analyse it: `analyse`
- generate the graph: `graph`

You'll get a graph in .dot format and a rendered PNG (this one was too large to post here).

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a call graph with [Gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html). It can be visualized with [Kprof](http://kprof.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning it, I'll edit to compensate.  I tried gprof, but the compiler set I'm working with is somewhat restrictive because Windriver didn't provide some of the libraries necessary to build a profileable application.  The object files build, but it's missing some crt libs & whatnot.  I tried supplying other crt libs that satisfy the dependencies, but gprof exits with a terse and cryptic error.  Perhaps I should be more patient with it, but I opted to look for other solutions rather than beating that horse.

Comment: +1 because it's a good suggestion for solving the more general problem, even if it isn't exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer but can still be useful.. On Solaris you can use `collect`.

- `collect your_program your_args...`
- It will generate a directory like `test.1.er`
- You can then visualize the call graph on the console with `er_print -calltree test.1.er`
- Or on X-Window with `analyser`

Comment: +1 This is a good one, with the caveat that you must have Sun Studio installed and you must compile your program with the appropriate arguments to instrument the process.